# Why isn't there any one-shot way of vertical centering in CSS3?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

After reading this [*"In The Woods" blog post*](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/), I wondered:

**Why isn't there any one-shot way of vertical centering in CSS3?**

Why can't I just make a `<div>` with the CSS attribute `vertical-align: center` and have my content vertically centered?

Comment: Why does it always rain on me?

Comment: Everyone hates this too.

Comment: Because `vertical-align` does something else entirely.

Comment: Don't forget our very own's [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name may be slightly confusing. The css declaration `vertical-align` isn't for vertically centring some content inside its parent (unless we're talking about table cells). Rather, it is for setting the vertical alignment of the element that the rule is declared upon.

This is useful if you're using `inline-block` to get some elements to sit next to each other and behave.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `vertical-align: center` if you make your container `display: table-cell`

[**browser support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to support the [Flexible Box Layout Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/):

> **Abstract**
>
> The specification describes a CSS box model optimized for user
>   interface design. In the flex layout model, the children of a flex
>   container can be laid out in any direction, and can "flex" their
>   sizes, either growing to fill unused space or shrinking to avoid
>   overflowing the parent. Both horizontal and vertical alignment of the
>   children can be easily manipulated. Nesting of these boxes (horizontal
>   inside vertical, or vertical inside horizontal) can be used to build
>   layouts in two dimensions.

And note [this from the proposed spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-containers):

> A flex container establishes a new flex formatting context for its
>   contents. This is the same as establishing a block formatting context,
>   except that flex layout is used instead of block layout: floats do not
>   intrude into the flex container, and the flex container's margins do
>   not collapse with the margins of its contents. Flex containers form a
>   containing block for their contents exactly like block containers do.
>
> *Flex containers are not block containers*, and so some properties that were designed with the assumption of block layout don't apply in
>   the context of flex layout. In particular:
>
> - all of the **'column-*'** properties in the Multicol module have no effect on a flex container.
> - **'float'** and **'clear'** have no effect on a flex item.
> - ***'vertical-align'** has no effect on a flex item.*

Keep in mind, this spec is still early and has already had a previous version replaced (by this one). So, it seeks to solve some common layout problems that seem like they should be "resolved", it's apparently still early to start calling it viable.

But we can hope, can't we?

- [MDN CSS flexible box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Flexbox)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)